# How to Customize ObjectId in Parse from swift while creating an object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, objectid

I have three classes for my app in Parse. Say A, B, C.

Whenever I create an object in A class, the object id should start with A and have 15 digits.

Likewise whenever I create an object in B class, the object id should start with B and have 11 digits.

I also want to ensure that the object id is not repeating.

Can I do them by any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not customize objectId, you can create another field with name customId and set its value whatever you want.